# How can I update the state of a child component from the parent component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried passing a function as a prop to the child component, but I'm not sure how to call it from the parent component.

```
// Parent Component
function Parent() {
    const [childState, setChildState] = useState(false); 
    const handleClick = () => { 
        // How can I update the state of the child component from here? 
    }; 
    return ( <div> <Child childState={childState} setChildState={setChildState} /> <button onClick={handleClick}>Update Child State</button> </div> );
}
// Child Component 
function Child({ childState, setChildState }) {
    return ( <div> <p>Child State: {childState.toString()}</p> </div> ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example you do not need to pass "childState, setChildState" in to the child function as it already has access to them.

Something like this should work for you

```
function Parent() { 
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(false); 
  
  // We have access to childState here
  function Child() { 
    return ( <div> <p>Child State: {childState.toString()}</p> </div> 
  ); }
  
  // Updating state
  const handleClick = () => {
    setChildState(!childState)
  }; 
  
  return ( <div> 
    <Child childState={childState} setChildState={setChildState} /> 
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Update Child State</button> </div> 
  ); 
  
}
```